# overfitting alexnet -- python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have an alexnet neural network that I wrote it from scratch using tensorflow and I used 6000 images as train_data.
but while training, the validation accuracy is not changing and it is greater than training accuracy, I guess it is overfitting. In addition, validation loss is increasing.
Is it possible to solve overfitting problem with 1000 data for saving time?
How can I prevent overfitting?
I attached my alexnet code below.
Thanks

```
def CreateModel():
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227,227,3), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(224*224*3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()
return model

alexNet_model = CreateModel()
alexNet_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
batch_size = 4
epochs = 5
history = alexNet_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1,
                   validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```

Comment: `validation accuracy is not changing` possibly indicates something else than overfitting. Validation accuracy starts shooting up when a model starts to overfit the training set. If the validation error stays the same all the time then it may indicate that there is low to no relationship between features and label or that the train-test split was performed poorly (no shuffling, unlucky draw), or it may indicate a ton of other issues. Sorry, but this is not answerable.

Comment: @Matus Dubrava validation accuracy is not changing but validation loss is increasing. I performed data shuffling

Comment: If it is overfitting then perhaps your model is too complex for the given task and is picking a lot of unnecessary details. There are few approaches here that you can try. Simplify the model (reduce layers, sizes). Increase regularization and use early stopping. This is trial and error process and there is no definitive answer which fits all models and all datasets.

Comment: @MatusDubrava your last comment really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate overfitting. You can try to implement below steps

1.`Shuffle` the `Data`, by using `shuffle=True` in alexNet_model.fit. Code is shown below:

```
history = alexNet_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1,
                   validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation), shuffle = True)
```

2.Use `Early Stopping`. Code is shown below

```
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15)
```

3.Use Regularization. Code for Regularization is shown below (You can try l1 Regularization or l1_l2 Regularization as well):

```
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2

Regularizer = l2(0.001)

alexNet_model.add(Conv2D(96,11, 11, input_shape = (227,227,3),strides=(4,4), padding='valid', activation='relu', data_format='channels_last', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))

alexNet_model.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid', 
                    activity_regularizer=Regularizer, kernel_regularizer=Regularizer))
```

4.You can try using `BatchNormalization`.

5.Perform Image Data Augmentation using `ImageDataGenerator`. Refer [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/) for more info about that.

6.If the Pixels are not `Normalized`, Dividing the Pixel Values with `255` also helps